# Moving a rig by his bones correctly

Tags: blender, rigging

I created a model and then tried to add armature. But when I'm moving the rig, some of it stays in the place (the mouth), and I don't know why. Anyone know why it could happen and how to fix it?

This is what I did : http://www.mediafire.com/download/fg86hdb82wjit6q/Alien2.blend

These pictures illustrate the problem: 
idle pose:
[image]
when rotating a bone:
[image]

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Your model is not rigged correctly, you need to further weight paint the model. For that you should set the object interaction mode. You can do this in the 3D view's taskbar where you can also switch between object mode/edit mode, etc.
 There is also a blender stackexchange now, you should go there if you have further questions, you will have better chances there I imagine.

Comment: I tried changing the weight but it didnt help.Thank you though for telling me about  blender stackexchange. i'll try there

Comment: It worked.
I probably didnt change the paint right at first. Thank you!